# Static variable and actionePerformed method?

Tags: java, static-methods, event-driven

I have a class called Windows. The class extends JFrame and adds GUI components to the JFrame container. One of those components is a JTextfield. I am trying to set the text in the JTextfield through the actionPerformed() when generator JButton is clicked. The actionPerformed() is a class called EvenHandler. This is the eventHandler:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;


public class EventHandler implements ActionListener {
    int x = 0;
    PassWordGenerator password;
    Window Window; // It works only when static Window Window.

    public void start() {
         Window = new Window();
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         password = new PassWordGenerator(3,3,3,3);
         Window.setGeneratedPswd(password.getPswd());
         x += 1;
         System.out.println(x);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventHandler x = new EventHandler();
        x.start();
    }
}
```

the window class if you want to know how the GUI looks like. The button is the one calling actionePerfome().

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Window extends JFrame  {
    Label passwordLength;
    Label labelGnPswd;
    JTextField psdLength;
    JCheckBox upperCase_letters;
    JCheckBox lowerCase_letters;
    JCheckBox numbers;
    JCheckBox symbols;
    JTextField generatedPswd;
    EventHandler event = new EventHandler();
    JButton generetor;

    public Window() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setTitle("PasswordGenerator");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);

        //Password Length
        passwordLength = new Label("Password Length");
        add(passwordLength);

        //Input text
        psdLength = new JTextField("0", 5);
        add(psdLength);

        //Create checkBoxes
        createcheckbxs();

        //Label Generated psw
        labelGnPswd = new Label("Generated pswd");
        add(labelGnPswd);

        //Generated Password;
        generatedPswd = new JTextField("****", 5);
        generatedPswd.setEditable(false);
        add(generatedPswd);

        //Button
        generetor = new JButton("Generate pswd!");
        generetor.addActionListener(event);
        add(generetor);

        setSize(200, 400);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public String getpsdLength() {
        return psdLength.getText();
    }

    public void setGeneratedPswd(String pswd) {
        generatedPswd.setText(pswd);
    }

    private void createcheckbxs() {
        upperCase_letters = new JCheckBox("Include uppercase");
        add(upperCase_letters);

        lowerCase_letters = new JCheckBox("Include lowercase");
        add(lowerCase_letters);

        numbers = new JCheckBox("Include numbers ");
        add(numbers);

        symbols = new JCheckBox("Include symbols ");
        add(symbols);
    }

}
```

My question is that When I clicked on the generator JButton I get an error message along the line, "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException..." I debugged the actionPerformed() and I found out that the Window Window is null when actionPefromed() is called after clicking genetor Jbutton. Why is Window null? Int x is working fine and it is not null. Isn't var x and window the same varaible scope. The only way I could keep the value of Window not null was to make Window a static variable.I hope my problem is a little more clear. Thanks in advance

Comment: It's unclear why you think it has to be `static`. Please clarify your question.

Comment: `Window` is a terrible field name when you have a class named `Window`.  Why not follow the Java code conventions?

Comment: your class and object names are same `static Window Window;` how does that work?

Comment: Are you sure you did call `start()` before any call to `actionPerformed`?

Comment: So I edited my question and I was wondering if the information is now enough to take my question off on hold.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems in this line in `Window.java`:

```
generetor.addActionListener(event);
```

Variable `event` is declared in `Window.java`:

```
EventHandler event = new EventHandler();
```

The problem is that on `event` `start()` is not called so its instance variable `Window Window` remains `null`. The `EventHandler` you instantiate in `main()` is not used. What you might do is delete your `start` method and put its contents in the constructor.